# I'm interest on accessing classes in php to echo data in OOP?

Tags: php, oop

How do i echo out the data inside a class in php , in Object Oriented Programming ?
this is the following code that i am writing if it is correct .Whenever i echo it out i have and error unexpected '$name' expecting function:

```
class person{
    $name;
    $email;
}

$person1-> new person;

$person1-> $name='Eliot';

echo $person1->$name;
```

Comment: class person{

    public $name;
    public $email;
}

$person1 = new person();

$person1->name='Eliot';

echo $person1->name;

Comment: This is what your code should look like https://3v4l.org/9UXm4

Comment: Thank you bout for the help now i get it , Thanx Eddie and Thanx Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  , you code syntax is wrong ,try this :

```
<?php

class person{
    private $name;
    private $email;    
}

$person1 =new person;

$person1->name='Eliot';

echo $person1->name;
```

If you execute the code , you will get an error :

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property
>   person::$name in [...]

That mean , the property name is not reachable . you have to add getter and setter.

The best way is to use magic method  **__get** and **__set**, so you code seems to be like:

```
<?php

class person{
    private $name;
    private $email;


    public function __get($property){
        return $this->$property;
    }


    public function __set($property, $value){
         $this->$property=$value;
    }

}

$person1 =new person;

$person1->name='Eliot';

echo $person1->name; // output Eliot
```

To explain more , Generally speaking , on all other langage , if you declare your attribute private or protected your have to declare get and setter to access those variable unless if not public . so see the example bellow :

```
class person{
    private $name;

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($newname){
        $this->name=$newname ;
    }

}

$person1 =new person;

$person1->setName('Eliot');

echo $person1->getName(); // output  Eliot
```

This is a common way over other langage , but in PHP , there is another way to do that , and if you ask me what this way can help us instead of the common way . i can told you an example if you have an class with 10 private properties , you have to create 10 getters and 10 setters (this is the common way) , but using magic methods in php , you will just create one getter **__get** and one setter **__set**.  (see more magic method [here](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.magic.php))

Here is the secret :

```
$person = new Person();
$person->$name = "Denba";
```

Behind , PHP know that you want to set the attribute name of the object person , like you make

```
$person->setName('Denba');
```

> So , because there is only one setter for all the attribute of the
>   class, your __set method should have as argument the property you want
>   to update and then the value you want to put in .

There is another Problem , if you ask me what if i try to update a property which not exist like :

```
$person->xxx = "Denba"; // xxx does not exist on the class
```

This will not break your script , and if you try to access to :

```
$person->xxx // this will return Denba
```

A clean way to verify before updating if the property exist , you can update your **__set**  to seem like :

```
public function __set($property , $value){
        if(property_exists($this, $property)){
         $this->$property = $value;       
        }
}
```

The __get :

```
public function __get($property){
     if(property_exists($this, $property)){
    return $this->$property;
     }
}
```

Hope this help you .

Enjoy the GREAT PHP .

Comment: Now this $property and $value inside the public function __get and __set what represent this in OOP ?

Comment: i update my answer , check it for more details . hope this help you